# There's a way to exclude properties from returned create() object?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to hidden the return of some fields when i do a `Model.create()`, but is returning the properties that i set in exclude array from `defaultScope`.

I tried to do this with a `defaultScope` but seems not work:

```
import { Model, Table, Column } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({
  modelName: 'user',
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
  defaultScope: {
    attributes: {
      exclude: ['password', 'confirm_email_token', 'password_recovery_token']
    }
  }
})
export default class User extends Model<User> {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true })
  id: number;
  @Column
  email: string;
  @Column
  password: string;
  @Column
  first_name: string;
  @Column
  second_name: string;
  @Column
  confirm_email_token: string;
  @Column
  active: boolean;
  password_recovery_token: string;
}
```

My service:

```
Class UserService {
public users = userModel;
...
public async createUser(userData: UserDto): Promise<UserDto> {
    const findedUser: UserDto = await this.users.findOne({
      where: { email: userData.email }
    });
    if (findedUser) {
      throw new HttpException(
        409,
        `O e-mail ${userData.email} já está cadastrado, escolha outro.`
      );
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(userData.password, 10);
    const generatedEmailToken: string =
      crypto.randomBytes(46).toString('hex') + userData.email;
    const createdUserData: UserDto = await this.users.create({
      ...userData,
      password: hashedPassword,
      confirm_email_token: generatedEmailToken
    });
    return createdUserData;
  }
```

This is my response:

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "first_name": "reeeen",
  "second_name": "ver",
  "email": "renve@hotmail.com.br",
  "password": "$2b$10$sPTkP/ZXHKwgvQCQQDvJxew.j5akj6nlnBMFyDzkOrNhM9R.BUOI.",
  "confirm_email_token": "2663029863af1177afebe94bca712a858e84347e108e95a22f5bf66050870c71266c3fb95562c0ee340061f9f950renve@hotmail.com.br",
  "updatedAt": "2020-09-08T04:18:41.173Z",
  "createdAt": "2020-09-08T04:18:41.173Z",
  "active": false,
  "password_recovery_token": null,
  "deletedAt": null
}
```

There's a way to delete some properties that return in my create() function without using `delete property`?
I have many properties that i will need to exclude and `delete property` seems not to be a dry solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no other build in param in squire for create function unless you’re in Postgres. So for your case scenario, you could overload the toJSON function in your mode class to create a new toCleanJson function that deletes al your params using the delete functionality of objects in native javascript

```
  toCleanJson() {
           const keysToDelete = [“key1”, “key2”, ...];
           const obj = this.toJSON();
           keysToDelete.forEach((key) => delete obj[key])
           return obj;
    }
```

You could also change it to provide an omit array to the function and remove the fix array give in example, and then you basically have what you would have accomplished with the sequelize param.